# Exception handling with RenderAction Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, renderaction

We are using renderaction provided by MVC futures.
We've noticed that HttpExceptions in child action methods are not propagated to the parent action. Even though a fragment has failed, we still see
the parent request resulting in a 200, and this throws our error handling for a toss. Any suggestions on how this could be handled?

Thanks,

Varun

Comment: Have you tried MVC 2 RC 2? `RenderAction` is no longer in Futures, and I don't see this behavior, though I may be dealing with a different exception than you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://forums.asp.net/t/1529174.aspx

Don't use RenderAction() from Futures.  Use the one provided in-box instead.  RenderAction() was officially moved into the framework as of MVC 2 Beta, and this problem should have been fixed.